# Backfill a daily table from deeply nested JSON object

Tags: python, json, pandas, etl, hubspot

I'm trying to take a, large, deeply nested JSON object that contains all contacts and their properties in our marketing CRM, and transform it to backfill a daily table.

The object is coming from [this api endpoint](https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/methods/contacts/get_contacts) with the parameter "Property Mode" = value_and_history.

The JSON object contains a list of objects for each contact record in the CRM, which contains another nested object with all the properties associated with a respective contact record (each contact has between 20-80 unique properties that I need to backfill for).

Within the object containing properties, there is a nested list of objects ("versions" in example below) which holds the property value and a timestamp from when the property was updated.

Example JSON object:

```
{
  "contacts": [
    {
      "addedAt": 1390574181854,
      "uniqueContactId": 204727,
      "canonical-vid": 204727,
      "portal-id": 62515,
      "properties": {
        "leadScore": {
          "value": "50",
          "versions": [
            {
              "value": "50",
              "timestamp": 1493910688065
            },
            {
              "value": "25",
              "timestamp": 1494022165157
            },
            {
              "value": "30",
              "timestamp": 1493011165157
            }
          ]
        },
        "lifecycleStage": {
          "value": "salesQualifiedLead",
          "versions": [
            {
              "value": "salesQualifiedLead",
              "timestamp": 1493911260146
            },
            {
              "value": "marketingQualifiedLead",
              "timestamp": 1493911177118
            },
            {
              "value": "lead",
              "timestamp": 1493011165157
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I've flattened the object into a dataframe in the structure below;

```
| contactId  | timestamp     | propertyName   | propertyValue          | 
|------------|---------------|----------------|------------------------|
| 204727     | 1493910688065 | leadScore      | 50                     |
| 204727     | 1494022165157 | leadScore      | 25                     |
| 204727     | 1494012165567 | leadScore      | 30                     |
| 204727     | 1493911260146 | lifecycleStage | salesQualifiedLead     |
| 204727     | 1493911177118 | lifecycleStage | marketingQualifiedLead |
| 204727     | 1493910832532 | lifecycleStage | lead                   |
```

I'm not sure if I'm headed down the right path with this approach. I think I could pivot this dataframe and join it to a date dimension table then group and ffill the dataframe, but again, I'm not confident this is the best approach.

The end result I'm looking for is a dataframe with a record for each contact for each day from the addedAt day to current day, with columns for each property, containing the value of that property on the given day.

e.x.

```
|dim_date  | contactId  | added_at      | leadScore | lifecycleStage    | 
|----------|------------|---------------|-----------|-------------------|
|2019-10-16| 204727     | 2014-01-24    | 50        |salesQualifiedLead |
| [...]                                                                 |
|2017-05-04| 204727     | 2014-01-24    | 50        |salesQualifiedLead |
| [...]                                                                 |
|2017-04-24| 204727     | 2014-01-24    | 25        |lead               |
```